# Accessing to a table during trigger

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, oracle10g

I have three tables:

> Customer(CustomerID,Name)
>
> CustInvoice(InvoiceID, CustomerID (FK to Customer), CustName)
>
> ProductOrder(OrderID,OrderDate,CustomerID (FK to
>   Customer))

I want to write the following trigger:

"Whenever there’s a new order in ProductOrder table, this trigger generates a CustInvoice"

I'm trying to write it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DoCustInvoice
    AFTER INSERT ON ProductOrder
        INSERT INTO CustInvoice(InvoiceSEQ.NEXTVAL,????)
    END;
/
```

But I don't know how should I access to Customer table during this trigger to access Name in Customer Table using Trigger!
Can anyone explain to me what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#CIHEIHAC)? Example 9-2 in that section should get you pretty close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to change your trigger timing to fire "after each row that the triggering statement affect". [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99888)

Second, in this case, there're CustomerID and CustomerName in ProductOrder's table that you can use by Pseudorecords. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DoCustInvoice
AFTER INSERT ON ProductOrder
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CustInvoice(InvoiceID,CustomerID,CustName) 
    VALUES (InvoiceSEQ.NEXTVAL, :NEW.CustomerID, :NEW.CustomerName);
END;
/
```

However, you can use select statement in trigger, if you need.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DoCustInvoice
AFTER INSERT ON ProductOrder
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_custname Customer.Name%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT Customer.Name 
INTO v_custname 
FROM Customer 
WHERE CustomerID = :NEW.CustomerID;
INSERT INTO CustInvoice (InvoiceID,CustomerID,CustName ) 
VALUES (InvoiceSEQ.NEXTVAL, :NEW.CustomerID, v_custname);
END;
/
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry there was a mistake in table ProductOrder that I fixed it. CustomerName is not in ProductOrder. So I don't know how to access it using FK to table customer

Comment: Just select the value into variable and use it. I edited my answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER DoCustInvoice AFTER INSERT ON ProductOrder FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CustInvoice(CustomerID,CustName) VALUES(new.CustomerID,new.CustomerName);
END
```

Comment: Not sure what the `delimiter` part is supposed to be doing, but you're missing the colon before the pseudorow references, and don't have the sequence reference from the question.